# Render an icon conditionally

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In a Datatable of Primefaces I want to insert an icon in a certain column conditionally.

This column has two values: 1 or 0, if it is 1 use the check icon and if it is 0 use the close icon.

I've already tried with "rendered", with "style", with styleClass, and it does not work for me. Either the read values are output, or nothing is rendered (the column is empty).

Is there any way to do this?

I pass a portion of code:

```
<p:column headerText="Vota" width="30" filterBy="#{vot.estado}">
    <h:outputText value="#{vot.estado}" style="float:right #{vot.estado == 1 ? 'ui-icon-check' : 'ui-icon-close'}"/>
</p:column>
```

Comment: `ui-icon-check` and `ui-icon-close` are style classes. Adding it in the style attribute  like you do is non-functional, put it in the styleClass (and you might need to add some other classes, with that in the browser developer tool)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the icon info in the style attribute while it should be in the styleClass attribute and you need the generic ui-icon class too.. So change your code to the following to make it work

```
<p:column headerText="Vota" width="30" filterBy="#{vot.estado}">
    <h:outputText value="#{vot.estado}" style="float:right" styleClass="ui-icon #{vot.estado == 1 ? 'ui-icon-check' : 'ui-icon-close'}"/>
</p:column>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<p:column headerText="Vota" width="30" filterBy="#{vot.estado}>
     <h:outputText value="#{vot.estado}"/>
     <i class="ui-icon #{vot.estado == 1 ? 'ui-icon-check' : 'ui-icon-close'}" style="display: inline-block"/>
</p:column>
```

Comment: Why so verbose?

Comment: Great improvement. Tried adding a styleclass directly on the `h:outputText`?

Comment: Maybe, but is not more readable keep text and icons separated?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rendered` attribute with the outputText itself, like below:

```
<p:column headerText="Vota" width="30" filterBy="#{vot.estado}">
     <h:outputText rendered="#{vot.estado == 1}" value="#{vot.estado}" style="float:right" styleClass="ui-icon-check"/>
     <h:outputText rendered="#{vot.estado != 1}" value="#{vot.estado}" style="float:right" styleClass="ui-icon-close"/>
</p:column>
```

Comment: You can even put it in one `h:outputtext` like already tried in the question but use styleclass instead of style...